# "Edit Links" in migrated SP2010 website vs SP2013

Tags: editing-menu, edit-links

I'm working on a 2013 Sharepoint migrated from 2010. I noticed that the option 'Edit Links' below the right navigation menu of a website sometimes is missing...and wondered why. My conclusion is that this link is only available on website created in the SP2013 environment. If the website has been created before the migration it isn't.

Is that correct? Is there a way to get it?
Note: I'm admin, I have all persmissions.

2010:

[image]

2013:

[image]

Comment: I thinks there is no solution to get that Edit Link back after migration if & only you change the site template.

Comment: `if & only you change the site template.`....i thought about it, but no idea how to do it.

Comment: It is tricky & you need to update the site template using the Power Shell command & it will affect the database of that site. So my suggestion is not to do it.

Comment: I'll try it....I let you know

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: If you are not able to get the solution for your requirement than can you please identify that the given information in answer is correct for you or not? I know it is true but you still didn't responded to it that's why i am asking you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you had used `blank site` as template in your SharePoint 2010 than that will not be available.

If you had used `Team site` as template in your SharePoint 2010 than you will get `Edit Links` option in both menus.

Please check below reference link.

[Migrating SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 navigation Edit links option not available / missing](https://jeroenvanree.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/migrating-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013-navigation-edit-links-option-not-available-missing/)

**UPDATED**

The old “Navigation” option in Site Settings still exists for editing Quick Launch and Global Navigation.

IF you want to change the navigation only than you can do it from **Site Settings** > **Look and Feel** > **Navigation**.

*The Feature is available Only for sites with Publishing feature turned on.*

**Hide all site content from quick launch SharePoint 2013 with CSS**

Edit your SharePoint page, Insert a "Script Editor" web part and add the below code in it (For Specific Page).

```
<style>
#sideNavBox a[href$="/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx"]
 {
    display: none;
 }
</style>
```

**To remove site content from quick launch of SharePoint 2013 sites, Add this CSS to master page, Or you can have it in Alternate CSS sheet.**

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: No it is not possible as templates used in both are different. Sorry BOSS...

Comment: If you get something than please let me know as i also needed that before few months but didn't get anything for it.

Comment: I don't want to change the navigatio itself... actually it would be enough to remove 'Site contents' from the left panel.

Comment: So you can apply CSS for that. This is simple man... Please follow this...http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/09/hide-site-contents-link-from-sharepoint-2013-quick-launch.html

Comment: CSS would be the last option....

Comment: Yes man..Please check my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40014/discussion-between-hardik-and-emaborsa).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the team site templates don't match when migrating. You can remove/modify quick links links in Site Settings - Under Quick Links.  You should be able to delete the "site Contents" link.

Comment: No, i'm not. If the website is a migrated one the option is not available.